# How to find a files to housekeep in specific directory name?

Tags: ksh

I want to housekeep some files in specific name (`/app/*/in`, `/app/*/out`, `/app/*/log`) under `/app` directory and housekeep it by `gzip` (if files older than 1 week, then gzip it) and `rm` command (if files older than 6 months, then remove it.

I had find command to list out the directory that need to housekeep.

```
find /app \( -name "log" -o -name "LOG" -o -name "infile" -o -name "out" \)
```

How I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

Look for files (-type f), older than 7 days (-mtime +7) and execute command (-exec and use as placeholder for the file and \; for ending the command)
I added a \ as the last position, so I could contimue the command on the next line.

```
find /app \( -name "log" -o -name "LOG" -o -name "infile" -o -name "out" \) \
    -type f -mtime +7 -exec gzip {} \;
```

Similar

```
find /app \( -name "log" -o -name "LOG" -o -name "infile" -o -name "out" \) \
    -type f -mtime +30 -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Note
You can avoid the -exec command when you want to do extra actions for each file:

```
find /app \( -name "log" -o -name "LOG" -o -name "infile" -o -name "out" \) \
    -type f -mtime +7 | while read oldfile; do
   echo "Compressing ${oldfile}"
   gzip ${oldfile}
done
```